# setPersistence does not exist in FirebaseAuth?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am following the Firebase docs on how to set persistence of my login: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

I have a Firebase instance via:
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

which I use to perform mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword. However, setPersistence does not exist in this mAuth object and I cannot find it elsewhere. Does anyone know why this is occurring and how I can properly set the authentication state persistence here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for the Firebase JavaScript/Web SDK, while you are using Java yourself.

In the Android SDK, authentication credentials are always persisted. You don't have to do anything for that, and there's no API method to change this.